# Updating publicClient fails due to invalid identifierUris on Azure AD application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-ad-graph-api, service-principal

I'm trying to update an existing Azure AD application using the following PowerShell command:

```
Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $objectId -PublicClient $true
```

This fails with the following error:

```
Property identifierUris is invalid.
```

The identifier URI on the application is "https://name-of-sp.verifieddnsdomainname.com". The homepage URL property (known in the manifest as the "signInUrl" property) is the same as the identifier URI. When I change those URLs to something else (I tried lots of options), I still keep on getting the same error.

With the "Set-AzureADApplication" I also tried the -Debug flag but it does not show me the underlying REST calls. Even with supplying the "-IdentifierUris" and "-Homepage" parameters, I get the same error message.

Also when I use the REST API "https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/applications/guid-of-application-object-id?api-version=1.6", I get the same error message.

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error? The supplied values for the URI should be correct in my opinion.

Comment: Looks really like a bug, I can just work with `Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $objectId -PublicClient $true -IdentifierUris @()`, if I use any IdentifierUri, i will get the error, but I think it should valid, because we can set that in the portal.

Comment: Yes that would be a work-around for setting the PublicClient property but also clears the Identifier URIs property which cannot be set again using the Set-AzureADApplication command due to the same error.

Comment: According to this thread a PublicClient shouldn't have any identifierUris so @JoyWang's comment appears to be the correct solution https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/7955#issuecomment-500265900