# Unable to create AKS 1.28.3 from Azure CLI

Tags: azure-aks

I'm creating AKS using the following command using PowerShell on Windows:

```
az aks create `
    -n 'mytestingaks' `
    -l 'westus2' `
    -g 'duotifysandbox' `
    --kubernetes-version '1.28.3' `
    --node-vm-size 'Standard_NC6' `
    --enable-cluster-autoscaler `
    --node-count 1 `
    --min-count 1 `
    --max-count 1 `
    --enable-managed-identity `
    --network-plugin azure `
    --network-policy calico `
    -o json
```

I'm always getting the following error:

```
Values of identifierUris property must use a verified domain of the organization or its subdomain: 'http://8c4b04.mytestinga-duotifysandbox-0aad06.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com'
```

[image]

What's the problem I met? I have no clue how to fix it. Need help.

Comment: Kindly check your Azure CLI version using **az version**. If you are using a lower version, update the Azure CLI with **az upgrade**.

Comment: How are you connecting, using a username and password or a service prinicipal?

Comment: I'm using Azure CLI `v2.56.0`. The latest version. I connect to Azure using `az login -t $tenantId`.

Comment: Verify the domain in your tenant: http://8c4b04.mytestinga-duotifysandbox-0aad06.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com, Go to Azure AD Portal, under "Azure Active Directory," go to "Custom domains."
Ensure that the domain you are using has been added and verified.

Comment: I tried the same script, and it worked. Try running the command without --enable-managed-identity.

Comment: @Will since you are using `--enable-managed-identity`, you might not need to specify anything about the `identifierUris`, as AKS should handle this for you.
Please use the below approach-

    `az aks create --resource-group <yourRGName> --name <clustername> --kubernetes-version '1.28.3' --enable-cluster-autoscaler --node-count 1 --min-count 1 --max-count 1 --enable-managed-identity --network-plugin azure --network-policy calico --generate-ssh-keys`

[output](https://i.imgur.com/fhaXGXQ.png)

Comment: Also, the error implies westus2.cloudapp.azure.com is unverified in your tenant. Verify your domain in Azure AD under Domain names, or use the default domain (e.g., *.onmicrosoft.com), which is pre-verified by Azure. Please try my above suggested approach and let me know. It should work if your id has necessary permissions

Comment: When I removed `--enable-managed-identity`, it works. The error message `Values of identifierUris property must use a verified domain of the organization or its subdomain` is really misleading and hard to understand.

Comment: @WillHuang did the above command work for you? Were you able to create an aks with 1.28.3 version using that?

Comment: @Arko Yes, it works. Can you put your explanation to the Answer area? So that I can mark as answer for you.

Comment: Good to know. Will post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you are seeing is related to Azure Active Directory (AAD) and the way that Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) integrates with it. When you enable managed identities with AKS, it tries to create or update an AAD application with the `identifierUris` of the AKS managed identity.

The `identifierUris` property is expecting a URI that uses a domain which is verified in your AAD tenant. The error is indicating that the domain `westus2.cloudapp.azure.com` isn't recognized as a verified domain within your AAD tenant.

You can verify your domain in the Azure portal by going to Azure Active Directory (Now called as Entra ID > Domain names and checking the status of your domain. If it is not verified, you will need to verify it before you can use it for the  `identifierUris`  property.

If you are not tied to using a custom domain, you can try using the default domain provided by Azure, which should be verified automatically (e.g., `*.onmicrosoft.com`).
[image]

Since you don't have any application or custom domains and you want to just create an AKS cluster with 1.28.3 version and you are using `--enable-managed-identity`, you might not need to specify anything about the `identifierUris`, as AKS should handle this for you.
Please use the below approach-

```
az aks create --resource-group <yourRGName> --name <clustername> --kubernetes-version '1.28.3' --enable-cluster-autoscaler --node-count 1 --min-count 1 --max-count 1 --enable-managed-identity --network-plugin azure --network-policy calico --generate-ssh-keys
```

**output:**
[image: output]

References:

- [AKS Troubleshooting - View errors from Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-kubernetes/troubleshoot-aks-cluster-creation-issues#view-errors-from-azure-cli)
- [Similar Thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1160801/kubeflow-on-azure-unable-to-create-aks-cluster-ide)
- [Deploy an AKS cluster guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/learn/quick-kubernetes-deploy-cli)

Comment: I think AKS should fix this bug.

Answer (score 0):

** **EDIT** **
Your command works from `Cloud Shell`.
However, in `PowerShell 7.3.5` (also in v7.4.1) with Az CLI v2.56.0, I receive this error:
[image]

> An RSA key file or key value must be supplied to SSH Key Value. You
> can use --generate-ssh-keys to let CLI generate one for you

Replacing `--enable-managed-identity` with `--generate-ssh-key` will work.
This will generate SSH public and private key files if missing. The keys will be stored in the `~/.ssh` directory.

It seems to be in preview though:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/manage-ssh-node-access#create-an-aks-cluster-with-ssh-key-preview

```
az aks create `
    -n 'mytestingaks' `
    -l 'westus2' `
    -g 'duotifysandbox' `
    --kubernetes-version '1.28.3' `
    --node-vm-size 'Standard_NC6' `
    --enable-cluster-autoscaler `
    --node-count 1 `
    --min-count 1 `
    --max-count 1 `
    --network-plugin azure `
    --network-policy calico `
    --generate-ssh-key
    -o json
```

I also receive an error that `Standard_NC6` is not available in West US2.

*Old answer, relevant for that error message:*
The error message you encounter that says: `Values of identifierUris property must use a verified domain of the organization or its subdomain: 'http://8c4b04.mytestinga-duotifysandbox-0aad06.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com'` suggests that the domain used in the `identifierUris` property is not a verified domain of the organization or its subdomain. You might need to verify the domain with Entra ID (Azure Active Directory) or use a domain that has already been verified.

Try this:

1. Make sure the domain used in the `identifierUris` property is a verified domain of your organization or its subdomain. See more here for inspiration:

- [Updating publicClient fails due to invalid identifierUris on Azure AD application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58217508/updating-publicclient-fails-due-to-invalid-identifieruris-on-azure-ad-applicatio)
- [Azure App Registration: Values of IdentifierUris property must use a verified domain of the organization or its subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77703185/azure-app-registration-values-of-identifieruris-property-must-use-a-verified-do)

2. It also mention that it might be a bug. Try clearing the `IdentifierUris` property by using `Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $objectId -PublicClient $true -IdentifierUris @()`
   Replace the `$objectId` with the actual Object ID of your Entra ID (Azure AD) application.

Comment: I don't have any Application at all. I'm just simply want to create an AKS.

Comment: @WillHuang I see. My bad. I did not initially run your cmd from PowerShell, but directly in the Cloud Shell. Anyhow, see updated answer. I also got a better error message; not sure why it differs...